# Proper and dense subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups

**Question :** does there exist a proper and dense subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ ?

An idea of such a group would be the following. Consider the following basis of $\mathfrak{su}(2):=\mathrm{Lie}(\mathrm{SU}(2))$ :
$$
i\sigma_1 =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & i \\
i & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
i\sigma_2 =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
i\sigma_3 =
\begin{bmatrix}
i & 0 \\
0 & -i
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Let $a_1,a_2,a_3\in \mathbb Q^c\cap ]0,1[$ be three irrational numbers between 0 and 1.
Let
$$
g_1 := \exp(2\pi i a_1 \sigma_1)
\qquad
g_2 := \exp(2\pi i a_1 \sigma_2)
\qquad
g_3 := \exp(2\pi i a_3 \sigma_3)
$$
be three elements of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$. Consider $H<\mathrm{SU}(2)$ be the subgroup of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ generated by $g_1,g_2,g_3$. We know that $H$ is proper in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ because it is countable (and it is countable because it is finitely generated). But I don't know if $H$ is dense in $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

Comment: How can elements of $\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1)$ be irrational?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry it's a typo, now corrected

Comment: You can also construct proper dense subgroups by taking subgroups generated by any two noncommuting infinite order elements $a, b\in SU(2)$. (Even "most" finite order elements would work.)

Comment: @MoisheCohen Yes that's what I found at thm. 2.1 in "On dense free subgroups of Lie groups" (E. Breuillard AND T. Gelander, 2002). Thanks.

Comment: @NAC I am also reading about connections on Principal bundle from Kobayashi and Nomizu. Are you interested in discussing one to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the closure of $H$. A closed subgroup of a Lie group is a Lie
subgroup. The subgroup $\overline H$ contains each $\exp(tA)$ for $A=i\sigma_j$ in your notation, so its Lie algebra contains all of the $i\sigma_j$, and so is all of $\frak su(2)$. Thus $\overline H$ must be
$SU(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but a possibly interesting little number-theoretic point: for any quaternion algebra $B$ over $\mathbb Q$, with $B\otimes_{\mathbb Q}\mathbb R$ isomorphic to the Hamiltonian quaternions, the norm-one elements of $B$ have a natural map to $SU(2)$, and have dense image (for various reasons). (Further details are not expensive, if they'd be of interest.)